# NSPopover padding content on one side

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, menubar, nspopover

I have two NSPopovers, both of which are set up exactly the same (just linking a custom NSView from IB).  Both pop up just fine, but one appears to offset the content by about 20px.

This NSPopover is (properly) not padding the content...

[image: no padding]

but this one adds about 20px from the ride side.

[image: padding]

Here are the two views laid out in IB

[image]

As you can see, the search bar should be pinned to the right side like it is the left, but for some reason it is not.  At first I thought it was a contraints issue, but after messing around with them for a while I can confirm it is not.

Any clue whats up?

EDIT: Decided to subclass the view and fill its rect, got some very strange results!  The view appears to be offset.  I have no clue why this is...

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but the comment `appears to be padding the content on one side by about 20px.` looks to be misleading.  The search bar in the app screenshot is exactly the same width it is in the nib screenshot.  This suggests that the problem is that it's not resizing at all, not that there's a right margin there.

Comment: Yeah that was my initial guess, but after running the little test I can see that is indeed wrong.  Now it seems as if the content view is offset by about 20px...

Comment: Add some logging to the `setFrame:` method of the custom content view class and also log the `superview`'s frame while you're at it.

Comment: @trojanfoe nice idea.  From that test is appears that the proper view is set to a frame of x: 13 y: 13 where the improper one is set to x: 0 y: 0  Time to dig deeper!

Comment: Okay problem solved!  I overrode the setFrame property and forced it to change its x and y to 13, 13.  Calling setFrame past this initial point has no effect, making the override necessary.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: One more thing to mention; if you're creating the `NSViewController` from the NIB then ensure the *File's Owner* is `NSViewController` and that the `view` is set to the correct view within the NIB.  This implies one-view-per-nib, which isn't what you have.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Proplem solved, but I still don't exactly know why it required solving.  The NSPopovers content view (or at least mine) requires an origin point of X: 13, Y: 13.  For some reason, only one of my views was getting this value.

To solve this, I subclassed NSView and overrode the setFrame method forcing its x and y to always be 13, 13

```
-(void)setFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    [super setFrame:NSMakeRect(13, 13, frameRect.size.width, frameRect.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like an answer to me.  Adding in guessed at magic numbers isn't professional programming. What's really wrong here that means you need those values of 13?

Comment: You're right, it's not an answer to THE problem but more a solution to MY problem.  I'll continue to look into it and edit if I find anything, but I thought adding the above as an answer would help any future comers drill down to the root of their problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/index.html), this caught my eye (emphasis mine):

> The principle circumstance in which you should not call
>   `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` is when you are not the
>   person who specifies a view’s relation to its container. For example,
>   an `NSTableRowView` instance is placed by `NSTableView`. It might do this
>   by allowing the autoresizing mask to be translated into constraints,
>   or it might not. This is a private implementation detail. Other views
>   on which you should not call
>   `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` include an
>   `NSTableCellView`, a subview of `NSSplitView`, an NSTabViewItem’s view, or
>   the content view of an **`NSPopover`**, `NSWindow`, or `NSBox`. For those
>   familiar with classic Cocoa layout: If you would not call
>   `setAutoresizingMask:` on a view in classic style, you should not call
>   `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` under autolayout.

Does it apply to you?

Comment: Hmm I never call that method directly, and I tried disabling auto-layout to no avail.  I have a feeling it has to do with the contentViewControllers view not filling the entire space.

Comment: @AtlasWegman So are you using Autolayout (constraints) or not (springs and struts)?

Comment: I've tried both, neither worked.  Here is my spring and strut layout http://cl.ly/OxvC which should have expanded the search field to fill the whole NSPopover but it remained the same as in the image above

Comment: @AtlasWegman What about the actual content view itself?  In my own use of popovers, I set my view's sizing like this (I'm not using constraints, if that matters): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18450868/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-14%20at%2017.40.25.png

Comment: Just gave that a go, no luck.  Good idea though!

Comment: @AtlasWegman I don't understand why that doesn't work... if the content view has a configured size then **its** subview sizes shouldn't matter.  The popover should be using the sizing attributes set on the view.  Hmmm.

Comment: Take a look at my most recent edit, it shows some pretty strange behavior!

Answer (score 0):

if you have an outlet to your content view, you should be able to force it into place with:

```
[contentView setFrame:[[contentView superview]bounds]];
```

or more modernly I guess...

```
contentView.frame = contentView.superview.bounds;
```

Comment: For some reason calling the setFrame method beyond the initial call has no effect.  As a result, I subclassed NSView and overrode the setFrame method forcing it's x, y to 13, 13.  Thanks for the response though!